# Can't detect built-in camera after installation

Tags: lubuntu, video, webcam, camera, modprobe

I have an old laptop (>4 years)with the bare minimum to work with. I installed Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and so far so good, my only issue is that the built-in camera isn't being detected by any app. I'm not sure if that's because the upgrade to Lubuntu or if the camera was already broken to begfin with and I hadn't realized. Either way, this is what I've done so far:

1.- I tried to install guvcview with apt-get but I get a message saying that I already have the latest version installed.

2.- I installed cheese.

3.- I've tried every combination of the Fn + (F Key) from F1 to F12.

4.- modprobe -r uvcvideo && modprobe uvcvideo

Also I haave restarted my laptop several times and I'm still getting nothing. If I run ls /dev/video* I get the "there's no such file or directory" message, same goes for /dev/audio.

Here's what I get if I run

```
lsusb -vvv
    
    
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               2.00
      bDeviceClass            9 Hub
      bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
      bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
      idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
      bcdDevice            4.15
      iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.15.0-140-generic ehci_hcd
      iProduct                2 EHCI Host Controller
      iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.7
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           25
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0xe0
          Self Powered
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower                0mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
            bInterval              12
    Hub Descriptor:
      bLength              11
      bDescriptorType      41
      nNbrPorts             8
      wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
        No power switching (usb 1.0)
        Per-port overcurrent protection
      bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
      bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
      DeviceRemovable    0xf0 0x00
      PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff 0xff
     Hub Port Status:
       Port 1: 0000.0100 power
       Port 2: 0000.0100 power
       Port 3: 0000.0100 power
       Port 4: 0000.0100 power
       Port 5: 0000.0100 power
       Port 6: 0000.0100 power
       Port 7: 0000.0100 power
       Port 8: 0000.0100 power
    Device Status:     0x0001
      Self Powered
    
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               1.10
      bDeviceClass            9 Hub
      bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
      bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
      idProduct          0x0001 1.1 root hub
      bcdDevice            4.15
      iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.15.0-140-generic uhci_hcd
      iProduct                2 UHCI Host Controller
      iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.3
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           25
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0xe0
          Self Powered
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower                0mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
            bInterval             255
    Hub Descriptor:
      bLength               9
      bDescriptorType      41
      nNbrPorts             2
      wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
        No power switching (usb 1.0)
        Per-port overcurrent protection
      bPwrOn2PwrGood        1 * 2 milli seconds
      bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
      DeviceRemovable    0x02
      PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
     Hub Port Status:
       Port 1: 0000.0100 power
       Port 2: 0000.0100 power
    Device Status:     0x0001
      Self Powered
    
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               1.10
      bDeviceClass            9 Hub
      bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
      bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
      idProduct          0x0001 1.1 root hub
      bcdDevice            4.15
      iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.15.0-140-generic uhci_hcd
      iProduct                2 UHCI Host Controller
      iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.2
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           25
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0xe0
          Self Powered
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower                0mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
            bInterval             255
    Hub Descriptor:
      bLength               9
      bDescriptorType      41
      nNbrPorts             2
      wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
        No power switching (usb 1.0)
        Per-port overcurrent protection
      bPwrOn2PwrGood        1 * 2 milli seconds
      bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
      DeviceRemovable    0x04
      PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
     Hub Port Status:
       Port 1: 0000.0100 power
       Port 2: 0000.0100 power
    Device Status:     0x0001
      Self Powered
    
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               1.10
      bDeviceClass            9 Hub
      bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
      bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
      idProduct          0x0001 1.1 root hub
      bcdDevice            4.15
      iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.15.0-140-generic uhci_hcd
      iProduct                2 UHCI Host Controller
      iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.1
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           25
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0xe0
          Self Powered
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower                0mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
            bInterval             255
    Hub Descriptor:
      bLength               9
      bDescriptorType      41
      nNbrPorts             2
      wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
        No power switching (usb 1.0)
        Per-port overcurrent protection
      bPwrOn2PwrGood        1 * 2 milli seconds
      bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
      DeviceRemovable    0x00
      PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
     Hub Port Status:
       Port 1: 0000.0100 power
       Port 2: 0000.0100 power
    Device Status:     0x0001
      Self Powered
    
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               1.10
      bDeviceClass            9 Hub
      bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
      bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
      idProduct          0x0001 1.1 root hub
      bcdDevice            4.15
      iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.15.0-140-generic uhci_hcd
      iProduct                2 UHCI Host Controller
      iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.0
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           25
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0xe0
          Self Powered
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower                0mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
            bInterval             255
    Hub Descriptor:
      bLength               9
      bDescriptorType      41
      nNbrPorts             2
      wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
        No power switching (usb 1.0)
        Per-port overcurrent protection
      bPwrOn2PwrGood        1 * 2 milli seconds
      bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
      DeviceRemovable    0x00
      PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
     Hub Port Status:
       Port 1: 0000.0100 power
       Port 2: 0000.0100 power
    Device Status:     0x0001
      Self Powered
```

And this is what I get when executing lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx DMI Bridge (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Long past end of life and off topic here. Lubuntu 16.04 LTS will be supported until April 2019

Comment: Thanks @David I'm aware the version is an issue, but is as far as I can go given the hardware restrictions I'm dealing with.

Comment: Look at `id;ls -l /dev/video`. Are you in the same group?

Comment: What are the "hardware restrictions"? Are they worth losing support for? Your system will no longer get software updates or security fixes. Your questions on AskUbuntu will be closed End-Of-Life. Other people's answers on AskUbuntu will become less and less applicable to your old system as they'll make use of new tools, new system management philosophies, etc.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator I'm pretty sure that I'm on the same group. As for the hardware resitrictions I meant I'm working with an Intel Atom @1,66 GHz, 1 gb RAM DDR3, 250 gb HDD emmc. When I first got the laptop, it had pre-installed windows 7 32-bit, so I wiped that out and instead went for a lubuntu of 32-bit architecture.